MySQL: How to find strings from a list of strings that don't exist in a column
Table Name: config
Columns Names Involved: name, value
The value column of my config table stores text values separated by commas like this: text1,text2,text3,etc
I have a list of 28 possible text strings that can exist in that column. I need a query that will report which text strings from my list do NOT appear in the value column for rows where the name column contains 'config_name'.
The following does not work:
SELECT value 
FROM config 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT value 
    FROM config 
    WHERE name = 'config_name' 
        and (value like '%text1%' or value like '%text2%' or value like '%text3%'));


This is one of the reasons why it's a bad idea to put comma-delimited lists in a column.

DO NOT appear... so you want to select data from a database that doesn't exist?  You'll need to 1st generate the dataset with the 28 possible texts so the database can return it.

I need a query that will report which text strings from my list do NOT appear in the value column for rows where the name column contains 'config_name'. Unclear. Do you need in a list of values which are absent in a column value for each separate row? or you need a list of values which are not present in your table at all? or maybe something else?

Put all 28 values in a table, e.g. known_values. Then use the LEFT JOIN+NULL pattern to find all the rows that have no match in the config table.
Use FIND_IN_SET() to match a value in a comma-delimited list.
SELECT k.value
FROM known_values AS k
LEFT JOIN config AS c
ON c.name = 'config_name' AND FIND_IN_SET(k.value, c.value)
WHERE c.value IS NULL

However, I recommend you normalize config table. See Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?

Remember that FIND_IN_SET() doesn't work if the words are separated by comma with space. It works only if the list is exactly as shown in the OP's example above (no spaces after commas).

One more question: How would I return the values in a single row (e.g. comma separated) vs. separate rows?

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(k.value)...

Awesome - thanks again!

I totally agree with this
